# missing excel web access webpart in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, excel-web-access-webpart

I'm missing excel web access webpart in sharepoint online.  I've google the topic and it says to enable "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection Features" which  i have done.  However, i still can't see the excel web access webpart in business data. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your plan for office 365?

Comment: Office 365 business premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business Data Webparts are not available on all of Small business plans, it’s only available on the Enterprise Plan E3 and E4.

You can get the details list of features across all office 365 plans check this technet.
[Feature availability across SharePoint plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx#bkmk_tableo365)

Also read this one http://itfreesupport.com/2014/12/in-sharepoint-online-office-365-under-business-data-section-excel-web-part-is-not-available/

Comment: Great, i saw it at a conference and thought it useful. You've saved me a lot of time looking for a features that doesn't exist on our subscription :-)

Comment: I'm on E3 and don't see it still; perhaps this answer can be updated on what to do in that case

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog, neex site features to be activated
http://itfreesupport.com/2014/12/in-sharepoint-online-office-365-under-business-data-section-excel-web-part-is-not-available/?unapproved=31847&moderation-hash=21055b96e657c3f4c4319ed507573bf9#comment-31847